# Getting pyHook and SendKeys to work together

Tags: python, winapi, sendkeys, keylogger

I'm trying to write an auto-correct mechanism in Python.  I log the user's keystrokes, and when they stop typing for a second I want to erase everything and retype the corrected sentence.

The code below is working fine, except for the fact that SendKeys is running very slowly.  I think the PumpMessages call is interfering with it somehow.  Does anyone know how I can deal with this problem?

```
import threading

import pyHook
import pythoncom
from SendKeys import SendKeys

# Store typed keys.  Correct words when stop typing for a bit.
def info_handler():
  def event_info(e):
    if e.MessageName == 'key down':
      v.keys_pressed.append(e.Key)
      if v.t:  v.t.cancel()
      v.t = threading.Timer(1, correct_words)
      v.t.start()
    return True
  return event_info

def correct_words():
  SendKeys('{BS %i}' % len(v.keys_pressed))

# Listen to keys.
class v:
  keys_pressed = []
  t = None
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = info_handler()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: FWIW, if this is intended as a utility that runs against all currently running apps (which use of hooks suggests), then this approach sounds like it may have some fun edge cases to figure out. Eg; if user is typing away in a multi-line window, and uses eg. the arrow keys while typing, any backspaces you send from then on may delete the wrong text. Or if the user does a backspace as part of their typing, you could end up deleting two characters too many. Also, in some UI, such as explorer, typing changes selection; sending backspaces there will change folder.

Comment: Yeah.  This was really just an experiment that I ended up abandoning due to too many annoying edge cases such as the ones you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I just needed to call hm.UnhookKeyboard() before calling SendKeys.

**Edit**:  Somebody asked me for more info.  I decided to just dump my key related experiments onto GitHub:  https://github.com/JesseAldridge/Keyboard-Tricks

Comment: Wait, spoke too soon...  Now I can't rehook the keyboard after unhooking it.

Comment: Ah, there.  PumpWaitingMessages in a while loop does the trick.

Comment: And...  PumpWaitingMessages is maxing out my cpu.  Arg.

Comment: Final answer:  use subprocess